# Orfeo Toolbox integration in QGIS

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox

I am getting this error:

> OTB execution console output
>
> '"C:\OSGeo4W\bin\otbcli_MeanShiftSegmentation"' is not recognized as
> an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 3):

That error usually happens when the program being executed can't be found. Try adding the **C:\OSGeo4W\bin** directory to your **PATH** environment variable.